# One year data only

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table donate.

```
SELECT nid, SUM(amount) as sum, month 
FROM `donate` 
where nid = 1221 
  and payment_status = 'completed'
  and date >= 1388534400
group by month

+----------------------------------------------------+
| nid  | amount| date       | month | payment_status |
| 1221 |  80   | 1388534400 | jan-14 | completed     |
| 1221 |  60   | 1388534400 | jan-14 | completed     |
| 1221 |  90   | 1388534400 | apr-14 | completed     |
| 1221 |  80   | 1388534400 | aug-14 | completed     |
| 1221 |  90   | 1388534400 | dec-14 | completed     |
| 1221 |  100  | 1388534400 | dec-13 | completed     |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

1388534400 is the datestamp of Wed, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT

where i would like to fech data only for one year, now if i run above query then i am getting data of dec-13 which i dont want.

```
+--------+-------+------+---------+----+---------+
| 1221|  100  |dec-13 |completed      |
+--------+-------+------+---------+----+---------+
```

i want data should be come only for one year. not more than that.

Comment: What is the value of column date in the last line? NULL? If so - you have problem in the data set. One solution is to filter out such rows

Comment: Your query returned that because your data is "bad"; if 1388534400 = Wed, 01 Jan 2014, then that same record should not have a "month" of "dec-13". In fact that "month" column looks bad for several records. which field is accurate? "date" or "month"? you decide.

Comment: it is evident you are using the MySQL "extension" for `group by`, this is not recommended. Your `GROUP BY` clause should have both NID, MONTH fields. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT nid, SUM(amount) as sum, month 
FROM votesane_donate 
WHERE nid = 1221 AND payment_status = 'completed' AND Year(date) = Year(NOW()) 
GROUP BY month
```

This selects the records from this year.

Use the answer of Wojciech to select the records from the last year (last 12 months).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub):

```
SELECT nid, SUM(amount) as sum, month  FROM `votesane_donate` 
WHERE nid = 1221 
AND payment_status = 'completed'
AND date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY month
```

Assuming that the `date` field is of `TIMESTAMP` type, not an `INTEGER`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`**:

```
SELECT nid, SUM(amount) as sum, month 

FROM `votesane_donate` 

WHERE nid = 1221 AND payment_status = 'completed'

AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), NOW()))) = 1

GROUP BY month
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return what you need.
If you need to drop the 'nid=1221' condition, this query also makes sure that your index on the 'date' column will be used, making your query faster:

```
SELECT nid, SUM(amount), month
FROM votesane_donate
WHERE
    nid = 1221
    AND payment_status = 'completed'
    AND date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 1, '-12-31 23:59:59'))
    AND date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) + 1, '-01-01 00:00:00'))
GROUP BY nid, month
```